# Excel VBA: Missing Project or Library on Chr?

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors, char

I created a VBA tool that took Excel data and input it into a PDF form. Works perfectly fine on my laptop. Sent it to a friend and she receives a `Compile Error: Can't find Project or Library` on the `Chr` in this line...

`data() = Split(WS.Range("K" & i).Text, Chr(10))`

I had her send me her list of references to... cross reference with mine and they were all the same. I'm wondering how in the world this is happening when we have the same code, same references, everything?

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet

Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS = wb.Sheets("Test")
Dim data() As String
```

Comment: There **has** to be a missing reference when she opens the workbook.

Comment: What is `data()` and `WS` how is it declared and initialized? Please show the relevant code or a [mcve].

Comment: @Rory that's what i'm thinking as well, but why would it error on `Chr` of all things? And she sent me screenshots of her references and they matched perfectly to what I have.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Relevent code added

Comment: @Bob the error is 100% she has a `MISSING REFERENCE` just make sure she unchecks it and it will work... As why it happens on `Chr()` I don't know but 100% there is a missing reference.

Comment: FWIW `Chr(10)` could be replaced with the more legible `vbLF`. Missing reference(s) break the internal name table, and you get these random nonsensical compile errors. Sometimes it's on `Format`, could be `Chr`, `MsgBox`, anything that is defined in a standard library. Cause is always the same: broken references.

Comment: Make sure she has your workbook open and active when checking the references.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same error, there is accurate solution for this error. May be vba editor corrupted. You can make a new excel file and copy all modules and sheet to the new excel file's vba editor. I think this not a correct way to resolve this error.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).